# express + route + how to display image file

Tags: image, express, routes

I am using express to set up the following route:

```
app.get('/Work10', function(req, res){ 

return res.render('Work10');

});
```

my /views/Work10.html file looks like this:

```
<h6>this is what I am working towards</h6> 
<img src="../pics/tabletoworktowards.png">
```

my file directory looks like this 
-app.js
-views/Work10.html
-pics/tabletoworktowards.png

My tabletoworktowards.png picture does not show up in the browswer when I browse to this page(localhost:8080/Work10). How do I fix this?

Note: if I open the Work10.html (by double clicking on it) I can see the picture in the browser. Just trying to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell express to load the files in the /pics folder.

You do that high up in your main file (app.js or server.js or whatever).

Normally what you do is have a public/images, and then:
`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

In your case you can do this:
`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/pics'));`

Comment: tks i had to change my html file slightly to this <img src="tabletoworktowards.png"> or this <img src="/tabletoworktowards.png"> to get it to work

Comment: If you want to use '/pics/some.jpg' then you could have the pics folder inside the 'public' folder and just reference the public folder in the app.use() statement.